# nSight eclipse edition remote cross compiling and execution

Tags: eclipse, cuda, cross-compiling, nsight

I downloaded the nVidia CUDA 5.0, because I wanted to try the nSight Eclipse edition
Since I'm a Mac user, this makes sense to me. It works just fine, but what I really wanted to do is to remote compile and execute (and debug) code on my external machines (both at home and at Amazon), which are basically Linux machines.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in Nsight Eclipse Edition. Unfortunately, current version of the Nsight EE does not support remote development so the only way to develop on another system is by running Nsight on the system itself (e.g. by using VNC). We understand that remote development is a very important usage scenario for our product and we are actively exploring the ways to provide these features in the future versions of our products.

Please also note that you may not be able to debug your CUDA applications in the VM environments (e.g. Amazon cloud).

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. Hope to see this fix soon, that's really nice option.